# Retrive External Drive Data on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, recovery-mode

Previously I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Dell Vostro 3458 laptop, on account of some technical problem in the display manager & others, I did a fresh ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation. I had a mounted external drive name **Storage** on **/mnt**  around 328 GB , where lots of important data belong to. After fresh installation that drive data contained on free space area but didn't get that data over there, also I got a **lost+found** directory after a made a **ext4** **Linux** partition named **Storage** on Free Space. Now how could I get those data(Directory, Files, etc)??

Related image info ...

- [Pretition List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F7OI.png)
- [Free Space that i made a partition named storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqncq.png)
- [Lost+Found Directory that i got into new create partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjYnm.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: First mount that partition `sda3`, then you should be able to see its content navigating into its mount point.

Comment: @vanadium 
It's mounted now, but didn't get those data that I mentioned except [lost+found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjYnm.png) directory.